# How to set order of events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, hyperlink, click

I have html-link, and I want to add event listener to `<a>` tag, so javascript function is called and after that brouser opens a link. I tried to use `document.getElementById('link').addEventListener("click", myfunc);`, but it works chaotically, sometimes myfunc is called, and after that link is opened, sometimes link is opened, so myfunc isn't called. How to set order of these events?

Code paths :

HTML :

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("LogOut", "Account") %>" id="logoutlink">LogOut</a>
```

Javascript :

```
function LogOutWithoutReload(e) {
VK.Auth.logout(function () { });}
```

`document.getElementById('logoutlink').addEventListener("click", LogOutWithoutReload);`

Comment: this shouldn't happen.  The event handler should _always_ be called before the link's default action takes place.

Comment: We can't debug this code with just those information. Please can you make a "working" example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: but as I see often it happens..

Comment: @user1495756 well you'll have to post some code so we can see, because that is simply not how web browsers work.

Comment: I have authorization on site and users can authorize using social network. I have code, that combines two types of authorization, not to make conflict. I can unauthorize from social network only using js, so I want to add click handler to logout link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your function doing? Is it some kind of aysnchronous event? If so then you would need to perform the default action in the success callback of the asynchronous task.

An example of this would be the jQuery `.load` function.

If your `mufunc` function were to call the jQuery `load` function it would return straight away, it will not wait for the data it self to be loaded.  What you must do is use the second parameter in the `load` function as a callback for when the data has finished loading.  This is the place you would then have your default action for the link.

This may be the issue you are experiencing with some other asynchronous task.

After you edited your code you have this line

```
VK.Auth.logout(function () { });
```

This looks like the logout function is indeed some kind of asynchronous call and has a callback function.  I may be wrong and it may be doing something else you would need to check the docs, but to me you should be doing anything you need to do in that callback function (for example the redirect).

Comment: Hmm, yes, really I have some ideas to solve it, using redirecting in code, but this idea is the best reallization of it I think.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The event handler will *always* be called before the browser navigates away. My guess is that your function does not work sometimes, causing a exception and not stopping the default action. Have you tried debugging it? There should be some messages in your (error) console.

Comment: You mean, it does *not* work? Where do have that alert, in the callback of VK.Auth.logout or before that invokation?

Answer (score 0):

set the link's href attribute after your script is executed.

the link

```
<a href='#'>LogOut</a>
```

the code

```
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(event) {
   //your script here, if there is an ajax request,
   // change location in your callback function
   location.href = '<%= Url.Action("LogOut", "Account") %>'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To prevent opening of the link try:

```
 document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myFunc();
 }
```

Comment: he doesn't want to prevent it, he wants to make sure it is always fired second.